# Why can you indirectly bind an rvalue to an lvalue reference but not directly?

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

From what I've read and seen you cannot bind an expression that is an rvalue to an lvalue reference. What I have seen however is that you can bind an rvalue to an rvalue reference and since a named rvalue reference is inherently an lvalue, you can bind it to an lvalue reference. What is the reason behind disallowing binding an rvalue to an lvalue reference. Is it for optimization purposes?

Take this example:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

void bar ( int& b ) {

    cout << "bar " << b << "\n";
    b = 3;
}

void foo ( int&& a ) {

    cout << a << "\n";
    bar(a);
    cout << a << "\n";
}

int main ( int argc, char ** argv ) {

    foo(1);
}
```

Comment: Just because the language allows you to contrive disaster doesn't mean there's a problem with the language. On the other hand, allowing lvalue references to bind to rvalues makes is essentially impossible to write functions that can be reasoned about sanely.

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2577623/some-clarification-on-rvalue-references

Comment: This has been asked before (more than one time). I'm sure you can find duplicates if you search thoroughly enough. Stroustrup says (either in D&E or in TC++PL, can't remember) that it prevents a mistake: `void twice(int& x) { x*=2; } double x = 1.0; twice(x); // doesn't modify x`

Comment: Related: [How come a non-const reference cannot bind to a temporary object?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1565600)

Comment: @MattMcNabb I'm not objecting to anything. Simply asking about the semantics

Comment: @edaniels ok, in that case I'm not sure what your posted code has to do with the question :) (see the q linked by dyp)

Comment: In the posted code we bind an rvalue reference to an rvalue (a <- 1). Then we bind that rvalue reference (really an lvalue) to an lvalue reference (b <- a (<- 1) ). This is valid and works. What you cannot do is skip the middle step and just do b <- 1 because of the rules of the language. The question asks why is the latter method not allowed if we are still allowed to do the former method. It seems like the answer is that C++ will try to avoid letting us shoot ourselves in the foot unless we really want to.

Comment: You **can** directly bind an lvalue reference to an rvalue.  `const T& lvalueref = T();`

Comment: Sorry I meant a lvalue reference to a non const

Comment: You cannot make the name of an lvalue disappear (without name hiding and without removing the object it refers to). The only place you can, namely return statements etc, already treat lvalues as rvalues and therefore allow binding an lvalue to an rvalue reference. On the other hand, you can easily give an rvalue a name and refer to it multiple times afterwards. That's why an rvalue reference is an lvalue.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's a fundamental rule of C++ and it prevents bugs:

```
int foo();

int& x = 3;      // whoops
int& y = foo();  // whoops (sometimes)
```

---

"Rvalue references" (a set of types; not to be confused with actual *rvalues*) were created at least in part so that you *can* still do this if you really want to:

```
int&& x = 3;     // oh, go on then *sigh*
int&& y = foo(); // you'd better be sure!
```

In the previous examples, I bind (or attempt to bind) objects "referenced" by an rvalue expression to a reference.

Now, I shall bind the object named by an lvalue expression to a reference:

```
int i = foo();

int& x = i;      // no problem michael
```

And to make sure that you *really* meant to obtain an rvalue reference from an lvalue expression, introducing the incredibly poorly-named `std::move`:

```
int&& x = std::move(i);  // doesn't move anything
```

These later rules came much, much later than the original, fundamental rule that has doubtless prevented many bugs over the past twenty years.

Note that Visual Studio has historically accepted `T& x = bar()` where `T` is a user-defined type; go figure.

Comment: can you explain the `(sometimes)` ?

Comment: @Matt: `int& foo() { static int xyzzy = 42; return xyzzy; }`. Predates my addition of `int foo();`. Perhaps I should remove it.

Comment: So when you say rvalue references are a category of type then I would assume lvalue references are a category of type. So does it mean that when I call bar in my example I am converting an rvalue reference to an lvalue reference since they are types? Or is the underlying object that is being referred to just being referred to become referred to as an lvalue reference?

Comment: @edaniels: Almost! Except that, inside `foo`, when you name `a`, you are creating an _lvalue `int`_ expression. It's not `int&&` any more. :)

Comment: adding on that, if the parameter a was int& a, when you name a would it then be an lvalue int expression not an int&? Could you elaborate on what you mean creating an lvalue int expression? Do you mean that anytime within the body of a that I refer to a, I am actually creating an int expression? Doesn't that kind of ignore the underlying fact that what is being stored is temporary?

Comment: Also just so I have my semantics down, when I say for instance binding an lvalue reference to rvalue reference I mean: rvalue& = lvalue&;. Should I be thinking of it as lvalue& = rvalue&; instead or does the direction of binding not matter?

Comment: @edaniels: [Correct](http://pastebin.com/5vNsJdtW) (and yes it absolutely ignores the fact that the original object is a temporary and it doesn't really matter unless you manage to create dangling references: that becomes the programmer's problem, though), and I didn't understand your last question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63067/discussion-between-edaniels-and-lightness-races-in-orbit).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I asked a couple of more questions in the discussion posted so that we don't bloat this :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well I think `int& x = 42;` is *not* supported in MSVC, they only allow this if there is already an object (i.e. only for class types).

Comment: @dyp: You're right; [it's only for user-defined types](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16495384/560648) (I don't use VS).

Comment: @edaniels: Answered there.

Answer (score 6):

> What is the reason behind disallowing binding an rvalue to an lvalue reference?

No answer to this question can be complete without a reference to the invaluable and distinguished source, [The Design and Evolution of C++ by Bjarne Stroustrup](http://www.stroustrup.com/dne.html).

In section 3.7 Bjarne writes:

> I made one serious mistake, though, by allowing a non-`const` reference
>   to be initialized by a non-lvalue.  For example:
>
> ```
> void incr(int& rr) { rr++; }
>
> void g()
> {
>     double ss = 1;
>     incr(ss);    // note: double passed, int expected
>                  // (fixed: error in Release 2.0)
> }
> ```
>
> Because of the difference in type the `int&` cannot refer to the 
>   `double` passed so a temporary was generated to hold an `int`
>   initialized by `ss`'s value. Thus `incr()` modified the temporary, and
>   the result wasn't reflected back to the calling function.

I highly recommend [The Design and Evolution of C++](http://www.stroustrup.com/dne.html) for understanding many of the "why questions" one might have, especially regarding the rules that were laid down prior to the C++98 standard.  It is an informative and fascinating history of the language.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `foo(1)`, a temporary `int` equal to `1` is created, and `int&& a` is bound to it. You can freely change it. The same way you can write `int&& a = 1;`. `a` itself is an lvalue, so you can bind lvalue reference to it.

You may read a great article [Universal References](http://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) by Scott Meyers which explains rvalue and lvalue references in detail.